# Finding the center of UIImageView UIImageView.center unexpected results

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView with the following constraints:

- Height Equals 135
- Trailing Space to: SuperView = 0
- Leading Space to: Superview = 0
- Top Space to: Top Layout = 0

The width of the UIImageView in Xcode 7.2 Size Inspector = 600.

In my `UIViewController` have an outlet to the UIImageView:

```
@IBOutlet weak var heroImageView: UIImageView!
```

In `viewDidLoad` the value of **heroImagveView.center = (300.0, 67.5)**

However this not the actual center of the image, 300 is way to the right of the UIImageView in an iPhone 5 simulator. Something more like `(x: 160.0, y: 67.5)` is center, though x is not exact.

In Xcode 7.2 the default width for all my UIViewControllers is 600 pixels, I understand that will not be the runtime rendering width across different Apple devices, but why doesn't `UIImageView.center` understand this?

How to I get the actual runtime center of a `UIImageView`?

Comment: instead of viewDidLoad , calculate center in viewDidAppear / viewWillAppear method

Comment: autolayout will finish calculate in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Answer (score 0):

At viewDidLoad, your heroImageView has a width of 600. Since the leading space to the superview is 0, the x position will be 0. Hence, the center is at 300.

You need to remove the trailing and leading constraints and replace them with a 'center horizontally', and a width constraint.